# Does Lagrangian Formalism Apply To Systems With Variable Mass?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass

Newton's Equations state,
$\overrightarrow { F } =\overrightarrow { \dot { p }  } $ , and we can treat variable mass system using Newton's equations.

1. While deriving the Lagrange Equations from d'Alembert's principle, I have seen that we treat the mass of the $i^{th}$ to be constant. Is this a necessary condition for Lagrangian formalism to hold? Is there a way to derive Lagrange equations without assuming this using d'Alembert's principle?
2. Also, where is this information considered when we derive the Euler-Lagrange equations from an action principle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to look at the general form of the Euler-Lagrange equations.

The Euler-Lagrange equations are simply,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_i} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i}
\end{align}$$

The term I you care about is $ p_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_i} $ which I call $ p $ because it is the canonical momentum. If you use the standard kinetic energy, this term becomes,

$$\begin{align}
p_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_i} = m_i \dot{x}_i
\end{align}$$

Take the time derivative of that and in general, we get,
$$\begin{align}
\dot{p}_i = m_i \ddot{x}_i + \dot{m}_i \dot{x}_i
\end{align}$$

Comment: When we derive the equations from d'Alembert's principle, where do we see this explicitly?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in the last paragraph of the OP

Comment: @DanielC Where variable mass is considered in deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations? As far as I know, it never was. The EL equations don't even require that the thing be a particle, let alone have a mass.

Comment: @Abhikumbale Not entirely sure what you mean, but perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle#General_case_with_changing_masses) helps. The Euler-Lagrange equations come from stationarity of the action. D'Alembert's principle is a bit different and permits non-holonomic systems.

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald thanks for the source, but can we derive a similar equation(like EL equations) for the changing mass ?

Comment: @Abhikumbale, Okay. I may have missed what you were asking. I had never seen the EL equations derived from d'Alembert's principle (I usually do action stationarity). I just looked it up, but if you take the principle to be $ \sum_i \big( F_i - \dot{p}_i \big) \delta x_i = 0 $ and use my $ p_i $ above, then the derivation is straightforward. Is that what you want?